# Using normal candlesticks as default in pine script regardless of the candlesticks type

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to use default candlesticks in a study? So, regardless of the user's selected candlestick type the pine script code will show the results and plot them based on the normal candlesticks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the regular candle's OHLC values by creating a link to the standard chart for the `request.security()` using a `ticker.new()` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator("realCandle")

[realOpen, realHigh, realLow, realClose] = request.security(ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker), timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close])

plotcandle(realOpen, realHigh, realLow, realClose)
```